# Hadoop jobtracker UI not accessible

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I've configured hadoop 1.0.4 in pseudo-distributed mode. Everything's good, I can put local files in HDFS and run wordcount task. But I just can't access the jobtracker web UI through localhost:50030, localhost:50070 doesn't work neither.

> HTTP ERROR 404
>
> Problem accessing /jobtracker.jsp. Reason:
>
> ```
> /jobtracker.jsp Powered by Jetty://
> ```

I look at the log files, but there's no error...

I used to have some problem with datanode, and jobtracker complained about replication, but that is solved and now all daemons are good (namenode, datanode, jobtracker, tasktracker, secondarynamenode) and no error in any of the log files.

Any suggestions?

Comment: checkout what's the value of `mapred.job.tracker` set in your `mapred-site.xml`. It might be `localhost:9001`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok finally I solved it myself, I had to re-install the system then re-install hadoop. I think the problem should be that I've previously installed the CDH4 on my system, which is hadoop 2.0.0 and even if I uninstalled all of its packages (debian system) and change the tmp folder of HDFS, but maybe there's still something left. The only way is to restart over.